# What buffers to use for stereo in Qt using QOpenGLWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, stereo-3d

I'm trying to do a stereoscopic visualization in Qt. I have found some tutorials but all of them use the older `QGLWidget` and the buffers `GL_FRONT_LEFT` and `GL_FRONT_RIGHT`.

AS I'm using the newer `QOpenGLWidget` I tried drawing images to the same buffers but the call to `glDrawBuffer(GL_FRONT_LEFT)` is generating a `GL_INVALID_ENUM`.

I also saw that the default buffer is `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` instead of `GL_FRONT_LEFT` so I imagine I need to use a different set of buffers to enable stereo.

Which buffers should I use?

Comment: I believe the buffers would be ``GL_FRONT_LEFT`` and ``GL_FRONT_RIGHT`` according to the OpanGL-Reference.

Comment: Hello, When I call: glDrawBuffer(GL_FRONT_RIGHT) it generates the error GL_INVALID_ENUM. And it's the same for glDrawBuffer(GL_FRONT_LEFT);.

Comment: That's because `QOpenGLWidget` internally uses an FBO (for whatever reason). I don't know if they implement anything for stereoscopic rendering.

Answer (score 0):

you should use

glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_RIGHT);
   glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_LEFT);

look this [link](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Nwo0CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT1555&lpg=PT1555&dq=draw%20the%20scene%20for%20right%20eye&source=bl&ots=LoTQVgIpm3&sig=6FsmKc0s1KSdZSBzNmE9mhHsJws&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjixJS9kfDMAhXHMj4KHbdaC5sQ6AEIWzAJ#v=onepage&q=draw%20the%20scene%20for%20right%20eye&f=false)

I am working on the same thing with Nvidia Quadro 4000 . No luck yet, I got 2 images slightly offset, the IR tansmitter light up BUT the screen flicker!

GOT IT: the sync was 60hz, I put it to 120 and everything works fine 
   I still need work on the right/left frustrum to say eureka.